# Shiny/Glossy pupils?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I want this white point of reflection to be on his pupils instead of the sclera. I've included images showing my material setup for the cornea, the effect I'm going for, as well as all the textures that came with the model that are associated with the eyes.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Shiny point" is a reflection of a light source in your scene, you can't control its position with material settings

Comment: I'm not trying to control the exact position. I'm just trying to limit it's position to be within the pupils like how it is in the example

Comment: You need to keep the light in front of your charecter at all times then so it can reflect the light correctly. Dont worry about the materials worry about the position of the light.